# Angular - Slow form rendering with hundred of fields

Tags: angular, forms, formgroups

I'm working with Angular 13, and I've build a form for a CMS with over a hundred of fields.

I've used standard reactive forms, and I have

- Nested formGroups
- Fields / Groups visibility depending on other fields
- FormArrays with FromGroups that can be added / removed dinamically

To made the form more usable, it's graphically divided in sections using `mat-tabs` with lazy loading.

Because the form fields can change often, the FormGroup is build at runtime using a JSON that defines

- Field type
- Field requirements (like 'minLength', 'maxValue', 'steps', ...)
- Dependencies from other fields for visibility

What I've noticed is that when opening the page, even removing the HTML part, the main formGroup is ready after 3/4 seconds, and if there is data it takes event more.

Unfortunately the code is proprietary and pretty big, and I can't reproduce it here. What I'm asking is good pratice on how to manage this much fields in Angular or ideas on how debug / optimize the code.

Thank you.

Comment: sounds like you should using pagination type strategy... only get the fields that are currently visible/usable.  (Those tabs shouldn't have any data until they are clicked... then get the field data associated with that individual tab...)

Answer (score 0):

- On push change detection, might give it a boost
- Try to do memory profiling and check where the most memory is occupied, `cloneDeep` or any `clones` of objects tend to slow down the application
- Try to do console.log(new Date()) over the code and check which suspected line take so much time

These are just a few suggestions, hope one of them helps you!